# HTTP request returns two http response back in one request

Tags: http, tcp

I send an http PUT request to my server, with the help of Wireshark, which shows the server returns two response back, one before the request, and one after it, the one before it is what I want, but why it returns before the request? And why it returns two back?
The server and client all in the same subnet.

[image: Wirshark packages]
[image: Response 1 TCP ports]
[image: Request TCP Ports]
[image: Response 2 TCP ports]

If you need more information, please let me know.

### Update

I use `tcpdump` to fetch all the packages, and the available packages is here 
 [foo.pacp](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gsqhq0jn1xwrgcg/foo.pcap?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

I think you read the wireshark dump wrong:

- At first you see in your dump a response from the server with `HTTP/1.1 412 Precondition failed`. This is the response to a previous request in the same TCP connection, but which you don't have shown here.
- After that you see the request from the client `PUT /objects/...`.
- And this request is followed by a single response from the server `HTTP/1.1 505 Version Not Supported`.